# SEC7117 Error when trying to load a javascript file in MS Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm getting this error when trying to load a javascript file from another server when using microsoft edge. I have a feeling it's related to the server being http instead of https, but I'm not sure. It works in IE (after allowing unsecured content), but I can't find an option in Edge to allow unsecured content.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
SEC7117: Network request to http://servername/whatever.js did not succeed. This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Same problem using cross-origin JS, CSS or PNG files. Way to reproduce : working on localhost:8080 and referring to files on my webserver ends up with this error

Answer (score 8):

It may have something to do with mixing the Internet/Intranet Zones rather than the http/https.

See here: [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/)

> **Private Network resources**
>
> Because EPM does not declare the privateNetworkClientServer capability, your Intranet resources are protected from many types of cross-zone attacks (usually called “Cross-Site-Request-Forgery (CSRF)” and “Intranet Port Scanning.”) Internet pages are not able to frame Intranet pages, load images or resources from them, send them CORS XHR requests, etc.

I know that this is an old post, but the info still seems to be relevant since Microsoft MSDN site still references it with regards to IE11 (e.g. here: [Enhanced Protected Mode on desktop IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265025(v=vs.85).aspx)). I also know that IE11 is not Edge, but this info might apply to metro-style apps as well.

[**UPDATE**]

In my setup Edge failed to load my page in an iframe. When I tried loading the page in a separate Edge tab, it loaded just fine.

It turns out Edge fails to load a private/local secured SSL page (iframe) when in-conjunction of loading a public secured page. Both sites are secured using public SSL certificates to prevent mixed content issues. The issue is that Edge security detects that the iframe site is located on the users local network (private/domain network) and prevents the page from loading in an iframe. Edge reports the following security errors in developer console:

```
SEC7117: Network request to https://my.company.com/default.html did not succeed. This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html
```

To resolve the issue we moved the internal site to a non-local address space (a private network space using a different subnet from the local network) so that Edge detects the site as public network. Alternatively you could move the resources to a true public address.

Comment: @MrBoJangles Updated the 1st link

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternatives to restructuring your network:

1. You may consider adding the externally hosted site to your "Local
   intranet" zone.

E.g. If **external.somedomain** contains reference to **internal.mydomain/whatever.js**
then add **external.somedomain** to "Local intranet" zone in "Internet Options".

2. If possible change the hostname of the externally hosted site to
   match your internally hosted site.

E.g. If **external.somedomain** contains reference to **internal.mydomain/whatever.js** then change **external.somedomain** hostname to **external.mydomain**.

Both of these options will essentially allow scripts on the external site to probe for HTTPS services on your internal network to some extent, which I assume is what this security feature is trying to prevent. The first option being the least secure as the second option is limited to probing matching domain names.

During testing, I noticed that Edge seems to get network details from Active Directory when Windows is domain joined. It's likely to prevent externally hosted sites linking to resources hosted anywhere within your AD domain, and not just the current subnet you are connected to. The one exception is if the externally hosted site shares the same base domain name. All this is apparently undocumented, which is why I'm posting this info here.