# MS Edge SEC7117 Error when loading PNG

Tags: html, png, microsoft-edge

I am receiving the following error when trying to load a PNG (over https) into an iframe on Amazon's mechanical turk:

```
SEC7117: Network request to https://toucan.cs.colostate.edu/pp/images/125.png did not succeed. This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer
```

You can view the page here https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=36TBNKR908TLAX7SKNTTRWW7TFYEDT It works fine in all other browsers.

I can't for the life of me figure out why Edge would be blocking PNG files (JS I can understand) and how to remedy it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**More Info**
Windows 10 64bit
Edge 20.10240.16384.0
Have tested on several machines and been able to replicate the problem
Have admin rights on all machines and they are not part of a domain.

**Update**
It seems to be an issue with the web server that is hosting the image which is running Apache. I placed the image on another apache server and everything worked fine. so then I tried to send the CORS header for all images as explained on https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/fc379c45f52a09dd41279dbf4e60ae281110a5b0/src/.htaccess#L36-L53
but that still didn't solve the problem. For some reason Edge blocks the request.

Comment: seems to be blocking jpgs as well

Comment: Can you tell me more about your setup? What build of Windows, Microsoft Edge, are you using? Are you viewing this page via a local server, online, or the file system? Is this a personal machine, or is it managed by an IT group?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Edge detecting the file server to be part of the local intranet, which is being referred to from a public website.

Related: [SEC7117 Error when trying to load a javascript file in MS Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860020/sec7117-error-when-trying-to-load-a-javascript-file-in-ms-edge)

The solution is to host the files on a different subnet from what the computer you're accessing it from.