# Loading image issue in Edge

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

I have a site that displays a image of the current user. The site uses Angularjs frontend and c# backend.
This works fine using IE11, firefox and Opera, but in edge it cant seem to find the image.
My html:

```
<img ng-src="{{getImgUrl('@User.Identity.Name')}}" class="headshot" />
```

Method in controller:

```
$scope.getImgUrl = function (username) {
        var outputURL = "https://myurl.com/profilepictures/" + username + "_LThumb.jpg";
        return outputURL;
    };
```

Style:

```
.headshot {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: what is the base url of the application?? do you have the pictures in the same domain??

Comment: The application is local,  and the pictures are online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. The app is an intranet app, and the problem was mixing the intra/inter -net. It resolved itself when I launched the app.
For more info se:
[SEC7117 Error when trying to load a javascript file in MS Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860020/sec7117-error-when-trying-to-load-a-javascript-file-in-ms-edge)

Answer (score 1):

In the getImgUrl function you seem to be referencing $scope.usernam (missing an e) This looks like a mistake also I'd have guessed you would want to be referencing the username that is passed to the function rather than a variable from the scope e.g::

```
$scope.getImgUrl = function (username) {
    var outputURL = "https://myurl.com/profilepictures/" + username + "_LThumb.jpg";
    return outputURL;
};
```

Comment: thank you, i misspelled when anonymizing it before I added it here. Code in question is no fixed