# Outlook web addin is not loading in IE edge ASP.net MVC app

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm testing our Outlook Add on in numerous platform, but for some it's not loading. For Outlook desktop 2013  and 2016, the add on loads just fine. The app also loads for Chrome. The only two that doesn't load initially is IE Edge or Internet Explorer 11. If I clear the cache and load the add on I get an error saying it can't be loaded, if I reload the page the add on loads on IE Edge and on IE.  Loading the add on on IE is never consistent. Any suggestions. My Add on is built on ASP.Net MVC framework.

Current IE Edge version: **Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**

[image]

When I look at the console for error I only get this.

[image]

I try debugging my app to solve any CORS issue, but the app never gets call call, so the breakpoints never get hits.

This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>fc188889-7206-4d15-9968-7a4966f7f4ca</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>PracticePanther</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="PracticePanther" />
  <Description DefaultValue="You can now work faster and get more done in less time by using the dedicated Outlook add-on for PracticePanther. Add new contacts, link existing contacts, save emails, bill for your time, and much more"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/68x68_brand_circle.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/128x128_brand_circle.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.practicepanther.com/law-firm-tech-support/" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44383</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44383/outlook</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://app.practicepanther.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain> https://localhost:44383/Security/Login/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlook.live.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- NOTE: Just reusing the read taskpane page that is invoked by the button
             on the ribbon in clients that support add-in commands. You can
             use a completely different page if desired -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44383/outlook"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>

  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!-- Message read form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                <!-- Task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/16x16_brand.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/32x32_brand.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/80x80_brand.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44383/outlook"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in Demo"/>

        <!-- Read mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Open with PracticePanther"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Open PracticePanther"/>

      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <!-- Read mode -->
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens PracticePanther to add contact, log email or keep track of time while dealing with your clients emails."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>

    <!-- VersionOverrides for the v1.1 schema -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">

      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>

            <!-- Message read form -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>

                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>

          <MobileFormFactor>


            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="mobileMsgRead">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="mblTaskPane">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="mobile25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="mobile25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="mobile25" />

                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="mobile32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="mobile32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="mobile32" />

                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="mobile48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="mobile48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="mobile48" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/16x16_brand.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/32x32_brand.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/80x80_brand.png"/>
          <!-- Mobile icons  -->
          <bt:Image id="mobile25" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/25x25_brand.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="mobile32" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/32x32_brand.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="mobile48" DefaultValue="https://app.practicepanther.com/content/gmailaddon/48x48_brand.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44383/outlook"/>
          <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44383/outlook"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="PracticePanther"/>
          <!-- Read mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Open With PracticePanther"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Get all properties"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <!-- Read mode -->
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens PracticePanther to add contact, log email or keep track of time while dealing with your clients emails."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Since you're running the add-in on localhost, one step that sometimes helps is opening the add-in's URL in another tab. If the browser returns a certificate error, and you accept the certificate, the add-in may then load in OWA. So long as Office.js is referenced, and Office.initialize is defined in your JavaScript the add-in should load. But if the page isn't loading at all, then you might try opening the URL(s) in other tabs to see if the browser returns an error loading the page.

Comment: It does open correctly on the tab on the same IE Edge process. What I find weird is that he doesn't hit the site at all to load anything.

Comment: Any other debug options?

Comment: I get the same error you posted when loading an add-in hosted on the same network in Edge. In my case, the error is consistent and only happens in Edge. You mentioned your error is intermittent in both IE and Edge. I also see the page not loading. Based on the error, it may be blocked by the web browser. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747370/7823505), which suggests that Edge prevents an external site from hosting a page located on your local network. The only workaround that applies here is to host the page at a different location while testing.

Comment: The error is intermittent when loaded on a public external site. When the cache is clear and we load the Add in for the first time we get the error I posted above . The add-in will finally start after we hit the "retry" button and then the start button.  The add in will always load after that, but not the first time.

Comment: After clearing cache, will the add-in site page load correctly for the first time on other tabs in IE/Edge?

Comment: Any news on this issue? We are experiencing the same issue.